# Problem after Google Services Version Change

Tags: android

Problem after change from google-services version 4.3.10 to 4.3.14

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10' -> no problem

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14' -> build error

build error message :

Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> No matching client found for package name 'com.unity3d.player'

```
//----------------------------
//build.gradle (project : ---)
//----------------------------

    allprojects {
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                google()
            jcenter()
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
            classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs "${project(':unityLibrary').projectDir}/libs"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I hope it will be fixed in the next version.thank you.

Comment: [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question? You can also read [ask] for further guidance. Can you please also [edit] to pose a clear, precise question? Maybe your question can be inferred, but this whole site is based on a framework of Q&A, so for the good of the framework, please ask a question.